# Random write Vs Seek time

Tags: random

I have a very weird question here...

I am trying to write the data randomly to a file of 100 MB.

data size is 4KB and the the random offset is page alligned.(4KB ).

I am trying to write 1 GB of data at random offset on 100 MB file.

If I remove the actual code that writes the data to the disk, the entire operation takes less than a second (say 0.04 sec).

If I keep the code that writes the data its takes several seconds .

In case of random write operation, what happens internally? whether the cost is seek time or the write time? From above scenario its really confusing.. !!!!

Can anybody explain in depth please....

The same procedure applied with a sequential offset, write is very fast.

Thank you ......

Comment: http://sqlserverio.com/2010/06/14/fundamentals-of-storage-systems-the-basics-of-spinning-disks/  The difference is that the head has to physically move some times.  The sequential write moves only the number of times required.  Q:  Is the disk you are using only used by your app?

Comment: Its used by only my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing all over the file, then the disk (I presume this is on a disk) needs to seek to a new place on every write.
Also, the write speed of hard disks isn't particularly stunning.
Say for the sake of example (taken from a WD Raptor EL150) that we have a 5.9 ms seek time. If you are writing 1GB randomly everywhere in 4KB chunks, you're seeking 1,000,000,000 ÷ 4,000 × 0.0059 seconds = a total seeking time of ~1,400 seconds!

Comment: The seek time will vary depending on whether the sector is in the same cylinder as the heads are currently.

Comment: Sure. But, boldly assuming the OP is using some sort of multi-tasking operating system with this application, it's quite possible that the operating system or another application will use the disk every time there is a context switch. If this is the case, then the heads will almost certainly be in the wrong cylinder when the OP's app is switched back to.
In any case, I was just meaning to illustrate that seek time can really pile up in random-access situations.

Comment: Sure, but with the memory on today's systems, disk access may not be impacted as much by the OS. (sarcasm noted ;)  Let us not forget disk fragmentation.  Knowing how large a cylinder is on the disk would be helpful.

Comment: Good point about fragmentation. 100 meg is certainly large enough for this to happen.
I don't think I can upvote comments yet, but I would if I could!

Comment: But how if I only seek and do not write it will take less time in fact very less time. I am not much clear still

Comment: Look at the seek time I posted: 1,400 seconds! That'a quite a bit of time just seeking around the disk, without doing ANY reading or writing. You're correct to say that reading is faster than writing, but the seek time will be unchanged.
EDIT: About Flash devices, I am not sure exactly what's going on. If I remember correctly, even something as fast as RAM suffers from a slight performance penalty when reading/writing non-contiguous bytes of memory. Perhaps it's related to that?